# Proxy to remote proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

One of our partners require us to use one of their proxies in order for us to reach various services there. What I would like to achieve is to set up a local proxy at which I point the domains, so that we internally can connect without adding/removing proxy servers or use separate browsers.

Our partner allows us to connect to http:// 10.20.20.10:8080, to reach https://application-x.theirinternal.domain. The proxy request therefor is "CONNECT https://application-x.theirinternal.domain", to http:// 10.20.20.10:8080.

I figure I should be able to setup a local squid, at which I point *.theirinternal.domain. A stunnel in front of it should deal with the https schema for the clients. No user authentication on the proxy host needed.

Is this a feasible solution, and how would I then instruct squid to always further proxy to the proxy 10.20.20.10 (as opposed to doing a real http connect against the destination domains)?

Comment: Can't you VPN to their network?  That's what I'd ask them to do for access to their services...

Comment: Tom: we use a vpn, and the proxy sits on their side. Policies and what not.

Comment: So you VPN in and they still want to proxy it? Strange people.

Answer (score 1):

Set the remote proxy as cache_peer, using port 0 for ICP (squid only?).

```
cache_peer 192.168.3.75 parent 8080 0 no-query no-digest
```

Add an acl that matches the remote domain(s)

```
acl companycorp dstdomain .company.corp
```

never connect directly when going towards the company.corp.

```
never_direct allow companycorp
```

allow everything towards the remote proxy

```
cache_peer_access 192.168.3.75 allow all
```